# Un-broadcasting Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

In a large code base, I am using `np.broadcast_to` to broadcast arrays (just using simple examples here):

```
In [1]: x = np.array([1,2,3])

In [2]: y = np.broadcast_to(x, (2,1,3))

In [3]: y.shape
Out[3]: (2, 1, 3)
```

Elsewhere in the code, I use third-party functions that can operate in a vectorized way on Numpy arrays but that are not ufuncs. These functions don't understand broadcasting, which means that calling such a function on arrays like `y` is inefficient. Solutions such as Numpy's `vectorize` aren't good either because while they understand broadcasting, they introduce a `for` loop over the array elements which is then very inefficient.

Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do is to have a function, which we can call e.g. `unbroadcast`, that returns an array with a minimal shape that can be broadcasted back to the full size if needed. So e.g.:

```
In [4]: z = unbroadcast(y)

In [5]: z.shape
Out[5]: (1, 1, 3)
```

I can then run the third-party functions on `z`, then broadcast the result back to `y.shape`.

Is there a way to implement `unbroadcast` that relies on Numpy's public API? If not, are there any hacks that would produce the desired result?

Comment: Something like `y[None,0]`?

Comment: What do you mean "minimal shape"? Won't the minimal shape in N dimensions returned by `unbroadcast` always be `(1, 1, ..., 1)` (or even `(1,)`  )?

Comment: I mean the minimal shape that still contains all the required data to broadcast it back to the full array. So in the example above, ``z.shape`` is ``(1,1,3)`` not ``(1,1,1)``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably equivalent to your own solution, only a bit more built-in. It uses `as_strided` in `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

x = np.arange(16).reshape(2,1,8,1)  # shape (2,1,8,1)
y = np.broadcast_to(x,(2,3,8,5))    # shape (2,3,8,5) broadcast

def unbroadcast(arr):
    #determine unbroadcast shape
    newshape = np.where(np.array(arr.strides) == 0,1,arr.shape) # [2,1,8,1], thanks to @Divakar
    return as_strided(arr,shape=newshape)    # strides are automatically set here

z = unbroadcast(x)
np.all(z==x)  # is True
```

---

Note that in my original answer I didn't define a function, and the resulting `z` array had `(64,0,8,0)` as `strides`, whereas the input has `(64,64,8,8)`. In the current version the returned `z` array has identical strides to `x`, I guess passing and returning the array forces a creation of a copy. Anyway, we could always set the strides manually in `as_strided` to get identical arrays under all circumstances, but this doesn't seem necessary in the above setup.

Comment: Or `np.where(np.array(y.strides) == 0,1,y.shape)` for the newshape?

Comment: @Divakar right, I keep forgetting `np.where`:) Obviously that's the numpy-idiomatic version, thank you.

Comment: For posterity, it might be nice to edit this to make the two key lines into an 'unbroadcast' function?

Comment: @astrofrog thanks, I was hoping that anybody trying to do this can turn it into a function;) Anyway, I edited my answer. Turns out that this results in an array that has the same strides as `x`.

Answer (score 4):

I have a possible solution, so will post it here (however if anyone has a better one, please feel free to reply too!). One solution is to check the `strides` argument of arrays, which will be 0 along broadcasted dimensions:

```
def unbroadcast(array):
    slices = []
    for i in range(array.ndim):
        if array.strides[i] == 0:
            slices.append(slice(0, 1))
        else:
            slices.append(slice(None))
    return array[slices]
```

This gives:

```
In [14]: unbroadcast(y).shape
Out[14]: (1, 1, 3)
```